# installation of 22.10 on asus ux301 not working, gave up waiting on root... dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, asus

after installing ubuntu 22.10 by following (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) on asus ux301, I cannot boot:

```
ALERT! UUID=<some uuid> does not exist. Dropping to a shell.
```

the uuid does not match anything in the output of blkid.

stuff I tried:

1. changing the sata configuration from raid to ahci - that cause no devices to appear in the boot list, so it just takes me to the efi screen
2. running boot repair - it didn't help but generated a nice report: https://gist.github.com/uriva/0e7cd45468c83de4540cd9a3fd9955c4